# how to make recently view products on all users on magento2

Tags: magento2

how to make recently view products on all users on magento2

so i wanna make module to show recently view product from every users and located this module to admin page,
how to make this module?

Answer (score 1):

recently viewed product data are persisted in the table `report_viewed_product_index`.

You also have `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`.

I would create a block in the same way as the default **Magento Recently View Product Block** and the data provider for this block would read from either of the above tables.

The subtlety with this task is not so much the block and database reading activity but more making this block dynamic may be the most difficult part of it.

Since your question is vague, I do not know how much understanding of Magento you have. I hope this level of details provides you enough to understand what you need to get your module started

Comment: where  Magento Recently View Product Block code located, and how to read data from the database